# JSON Schema - combining allOf and anyOf to make a flexible schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

In plain English, I want a flexible schema that will allow an object called "message" to contain a couple of string props, and then a 3rd prop that can be either a **plain** string **or** another object. So, if it's defined thusly, is this achieving the goal or is there a validation gotcha that I am missing?

```
  "message": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "another": {
        "$ref": "another.schema.json"
      },
      "@type": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "One",
          "Two",
          "Three"
        ]
      }
    },
    "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#message"
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "plainolstring": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            {
              "obj": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "type": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

And that would validate against either

```
"message": {
    "another": "blah",
    "@type": "foo",
    "plainolstring": "sdfSR345w34"
}
```

or

```
"message": {
    "another": "blah",
    "@type": "foo",
    "obj": { 
        "id":"sdfSR345w34",
        "type": "guid"
    }
}
```

Validating [here against Schema v7](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) says that it is valid, but while it may be syntactically correct, would it achieve what I want?

Comment: You have an error in your $ref, but that's orthogonal to the question you asked, and I can't assume you posted the full schema anyway. But you need to make sure that $ref points to a valid location in the schema (either a json pointer to a local subschema, or a URI defined with an $id keyword.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `anyOf` will do what you want - except you have a syntax error by wrapping the subschemas with those properties "plainolstring" and "obj".  The correct form would be:

```
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "type": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```

Moreover, you don't even need the anyOf -- you can simplify that subschema to:

```
        {
          "type": ["string", "object"],
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
```

The `properties` keyword itself does not enforce that the type must be an object -- you need to use `type` for that. `properties` just says "*if* this is an object, this is the definition of those properties".